# Insert data to database using AJAX (ASP.NET MVC )

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have table with Question1 -  Question10

Here is table syntax

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuestionBlocks] (
[Block_ID]     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Question1]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question2]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question3]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question4]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question5]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question6]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question7]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question8]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question9]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question10]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
```

Also I have DropDownLists for those questions

Here is it's looks like

[image]
[image]

I need on button click get data from DropdownLists and write Question1-Question10 rows in Database.

Here is My Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Question1 = new  SelectList(db.Questions,"QuestionId","question");
        ViewBag.Question2 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "QuestionId", "question");
        ViewBag.Question3 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "QuestionId", "question");
        ViewBag.Question4 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "QuestionId", "question");
        ViewBag.Question5 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "QuestionId", "question");
        ViewBag.Question6 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "QuestionId", "question");
        ViewBag.Question7 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "QuestionId", "question");
        ViewBag.Question8 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "QuestionId", "question");
        ViewBag.Question9 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "QuestionId", "question");
        ViewBag.Question10 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "QuestionId", "question");

        return View(db.Questions.ToList());
    }
```

And here is View

```
  <div class="title2" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px; padding-top: 10px">
                @Html.DropDownList("Question1", null, "Вопрос 1", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control", @style = "height:40px;margin-bottom: 20px;",placeholder="lol"})
                @Html.DropDownList("Question2", null, "Вопрос 2", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control", @style = "height:40px; margin-bottom: 20px;"})
                @Html.DropDownList("Question3", null, "Вопрос 3", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control", @style = "height:40px; margin-bottom: 20px;"})
                @Html.DropDownList("Question4", null, "Вопрос 4", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control", @style = "height:40px; margin-bottom: 20px;"})
                @Html.DropDownList("Question5", null, "Вопрос 5", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control", @style = "height:40px; margin-bottom: 20px;"})
                @Html.DropDownList("Question6", null, "Вопрос 6", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control", @style = "height:40px; margin-bottom: 20px;"})
                @Html.DropDownList("Question7", null, "Вопрос 7", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control", @style = "height:40px; margin-bottom: 20px;"})
                @Html.DropDownList("Question8", null, "Вопрос 8", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control", @style = "height:40px; margin-bottom: 20px;"})
                @Html.DropDownList("Question9", null, "Вопрос 9", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control", @style = "height:40px; margin-bottom: 20px;"})
                @Html.DropDownList("Question10", null, "Вопрос 10", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control", @style = "height:40px; margin-bottom: 20px;"})
            </div>
```

I think AJAX can do this, but how I need to write code or where I can write about how to do this?

Thank's

**UPDATE**

Thank's Prasanna Kumar J for answer

I have one more question

I write function and try to run it by button click
I write this code in html

```
<input id="save" type="button" value="Save" onclick="save();"/>
```

And this in JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#save').click(function () {
        save();
    });
});
```

But function doesn't run on button. Where is error?

Comment: you need selected questions only post to save?

Comment: Yes get values from dropdownLists and post to table@PrasannaKumarJ

Comment: The problem is your model is not bound to the fields and that's why the answers bellow try to use plain html to retrieve values by post and asp.net instead of MVC Razor. If you just Google for a full example on how to bind your model in MVC you'll get a clean solution.

Comment: remove the code onclick="save();" on input tag

Answer (score 0):

You're using ASP.NET MVC, so in your questions controller, you can create a `[HttpPost]` method to handle database updates.

If you're using SQL Server, you can use the classes in the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespaces and take a look at [MSDN documentation with examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8).

If you're using MySQL, you can use the MySQL .NET Connector - information available [on their site](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) including [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/).

In the database update method, you can use an `UPDATE` or `INSERT` query to update the data in the database. To retreive the information, have a `<form method="post" action="your_update_page">` and a `<input type="submit" />`. This will post the information contained within input fields (with required names equivalent to parameters in update method) to be accessed by your back-end controller to make database updates when triggered.

Comment: Razor should be generating the html form using helper Html.BeginForm and then you just receive the model as parameter in the controller when page is posted. Don't even need to specify httppost as that's the default.

Comment: There are lots of ways to go about this. Razor can generate the form if needed and there's plenty of documentation for it at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
In Client Side

```
function save()
{
 $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            dataType: 'Json',
            data: { question1: $('#question1').val(),
                    question2: $('#question2').val(),
                    question3: $('#question3').val(),
                    question4: $('#question4').val(),
                    question5: $('#question5').val(),
                    question6: $('#question6').val(),
                    question7: $('#question7').val(),
                    question8: $('#question8').val(),
                    question9: $('#question9').val(),
                    question10: $('#question10').val()
            },
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveAction", "SaveController")',
            success: function (da) {
                if (da.Result == "Success") {
                 alert('saved sucessfully')


                } else {

                    alert( 'Error'+ da.Message);
                }
            },
            error: function (da) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
}
```

In server Side

```
  [httppost]
  public ActionResult SaveAction(string question1,string question2,string question3,.....,string question10)
  {
        //do something
 return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Comment: So I can make collection on server side like this?

`QuestionBlock question = new QuestionBlock
            {
                Question1 = question1,
                Question2 = question2,
                Question3 = question3
                // …
            };`

Comment: provide correct controller name.what is your controller name?

Comment: `url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Questions")`  write like this

Controller is `Questions`

Comment: try like this in server side saveaction(string question1,string question2,string question3,.....,string question10)

Comment: have this `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` and controller name

Comment: this problem occured by incorrect passing no. of parameter or invalid datatype passed to server

Comment: url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Questions") index action is wrong change to url: '@Url.Action("SaveAction", "Questions")

Comment: all ok, new Entry is created. but it create id and not enter questions